# ethers.js ContractFactory not deploying

Tags: contract-deployment, ethers.js

After following the ethersjs 4.0 documentation I am not able to deploy a contract.  When running browserify I get an "Unexpected Token" error message at the line

```
let contract = await factory.deploy("Hello World");
```

The only npm packages I installed were browserify and ethers.
The following is my code in full.

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

// The Contract interface
let abi = [
    "event ValueChanged(address indexed author, string oldValue, string newValue)",
    "constructor(string value)",
    "function getValue() view returns (string value)",
    "function setValue(string value)"
];

// The bytecode from Solidity, compiling the above source
let bytecode = "0x608060405234801561001057600080fd5b506040516105bd3803806105bd8339" +
                 "8101604081815282518183526000805460026000196101006001841615020190" +
                 "91160492840183905293019233927fe826f71647b8486f2bae59832124c70792" +
                 "fba044036720a54ec8dacdd5df4fcb9285919081906020820190606083019086" +
                 "9080156100cd5780601f106100a2576101008083540402835291602001916100" +
                 "cd565b820191906000526020600020905b815481529060010190602001808311" +
                 "6100b057829003601f168201915b505083810382528451815284516020918201" +
                 "9186019080838360005b838110156101015781810151838201526020016100e9" +
                 "565b50505050905090810190601f16801561012e578082038051600183602003" +
                 "6101000a031916815260200191505b5094505050505060405180910390a28051" +
                 "610150906000906020840190610157565b50506101f2565b8280546001816001" +
                 "16156101000203166002900490600052602060002090601f0160209004810192" +
                 "82601f1061019857805160ff19168380011785556101c5565b82800160010185" +
                 "5582156101c5579182015b828111156101c55782518255916020019190600101" +
                 "906101aa565b506101d19291506101d5565b5090565b6101ef91905b80821115" +
                 "6101d157600081556001016101db565b90565b6103bc806102016000396000f3" +
                 "0060806040526004361061004b5763ffffffff7c010000000000000000000000" +
                 "0000000000000000000000000000000000600035041663209652558114610050" +
                 "57806393a09352146100da575b600080fd5b34801561005c57600080fd5b5061" +
                 "0065610135565b60408051602080825283518183015283519192839290830191" +
                 "85019080838360005b8381101561009f57818101518382015260200161008756" +
                 "5b50505050905090810190601f1680156100cc57808203805160018360200361" +
                 "01000a031916815260200191505b509250505060405180910390f35b34801561" +
                 "00e657600080fd5b506040805160206004803580820135601f81018490048402" +
                 "8501840190955284845261013394369492936024939284019190819084018382" +
                 "80828437509497506101cc9650505050505050565b005b600080546040805160" +
                 "20601f6002600019610100600188161502019095169490940493840181900481" +
                 "0282018101909252828152606093909290918301828280156101c15780601f10" +
                 "610196576101008083540402835291602001916101c1565b8201919060005260" +
                 "20600020905b8154815290600101906020018083116101a457829003601f1682" +
                 "01915b505050505090505b90565b604080518181526000805460026000196101" +
                 "00600184161502019091160492820183905233927fe826f71647b8486f2bae59" +
                 "832124c70792fba044036720a54ec8dacdd5df4fcb9285918190602082019060" +
                 "60830190869080156102715780601f1061024657610100808354040283529160" +
                 "200191610271565b820191906000526020600020905b81548152906001019060" +
                 "200180831161025457829003601f168201915b50508381038252845181528451" +
                 "60209182019186019080838360005b838110156102a557818101518382015260" +
                 "200161028d565b50505050905090810190601f1680156102d257808203805160" +
                 "01836020036101000a031916815260200191505b509450505050506040518091" +
                 "0390a280516102f49060009060208401906102f8565b5050565b828054600181" +
                 "600116156101000203166002900490600052602060002090601f016020900481" +
                 "019282601f1061033957805160ff1916838001178555610366565b8280016001" +
                 "0185558215610366579182015b82811115610366578251825591602001919060" +
                 "01019061034b565b50610372929150610376565b5090565b6101c991905b8082" +
                 "1115610372576000815560010161037c5600a165627a7a723058202225a35c50" +
                 "7b31ac6df494f4be31057c7202b5084c592bdb9b29f232407abeac0029";


// Connect to the network
let provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider('ropsten');

// Load the wallet to deploy the contract with
let privateKey = '0x...'; //my private key
let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

// Create an instance of a Contract Factory
let factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, wallet);

// Notice we pass in "Hello World" as the parameter to the constructor
let contract = await factory.deploy("Hello World");

// The address the Contract WILL have once mined
// See: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x2bd9aaa2953f988153c8629926d22a6a5f69b14e
console.log(contract.address);
// "0x2bD9aAa2953F988153c8629926D22A6a5F69b14E"

// The transaction that was sent to the network to deploy the Contract
// See: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x159b76843662a15bd67e482dcfbee55e8e44efad26c5a614245e12a00d4b1a51
console.log(contract.deployTransaction.hash);
// "0x159b76843662a15bd67e482dcfbee55e8e44efad26c5a614245e12a00d4b1a51"

// The contract is NOT deployed yet; we must wait until it is mined
await contract.deployed()
```

Thinking that maybe the abi and bytecode were specific to a compiler version I have tried pasting the solidity code from the docs and generating new abi and bytecode but that didn't work either.

Is there something simple that I am missing?

Comment: Where is the unexpected token in that line? The full error message should have a number in it denoting it's position. The error message also is a generic _javascript_ error, and not necessarily to do with the `ethers` library. In this case specifically, since the line in question is not _inside_ a function where `async` is declared, the issue may well be with the `await` keyword...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posted the question to github and got the response

> You will need to include this code inside an async function block. I
>   should update the documentation to include that, for example, you can
>   change the code at the bottom to:

```
(async function() {
    let factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, wallet);
    let contract = await factory.deploy("Hello World");
    console.log(contract.address);
    console.log(contract.deployTransaction.hash);
    await contract.deployed()  })();
```

> I think that should solve your issue... Let me know if there are still
>   issues, and I'll update the documentation to include an IIFE wrapper
>   for the async part.